# How to bring pictures to the front, and send pictures to the back - Java

Tags: java, image, applet

I have a few pictures piled on top of each other.
I need a way for the user to be able to bring certain images to the front, to view, when they want, and send them back when they want. Is there a simple code for this? Any help would be appreciated.
I am using Java.awt.applet.

Answer (score 0):

The closest and easiest thing I can think of is a [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)